# Creating a footnote in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, editing, documents, documentation, footnote

How I can create footnotes in MS Word? I do not want to create a page footer because that would appear in all pages, but I need to write some things as footnotes on a specific page.

I want to add more details in about some terms, but the details are not part of main text. For example like this:

[image]

Comment: "Feuilleton" seems to be "a part of a newspaper or magazine devoted to fiction, criticism, or light literature". Can you explain further what it is you want to do exactly?

Comment: @Karan Thank you for your attention,I added more details.Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inserting a *footnote* (which is what you seem to mean as shown in your image) is quite easy and can be done using the appropriate button on the **References** tab:

[image: 1]

You can also access further footnote-related settings as shown below:

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Further reading/viewing:

- [Insert, delete, or edit footnotes and endnotes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-delete-or-edit-footnotes-and-endnotes-54a7235b-6488-4b88-8ee7-f3d66d3372d9)
- [Footnotes in Word 2013](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Footnotes-in-Word-2013-eb4c92f1-dc07-4ebe-92a9-3326820e6142)
- [How to Add a Footnote to Microsoft Word](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Footnote-to-Microsoft-Word)